# How to set and retrieve presence status (online/busy/offline) using phoenix presence

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to get users presence states for small chat app written using phoenix framework.
status: online/offline/busy/away

This is the commented code segment:

```
defmodule PhoenixChat.Presence do
  @moduledoc """
  Provides presence tracking to channels and processes.

  See the [`Phoenix.Presence`](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html)
  docs for more details.

  ## Usage

  Presences can be tracked in your channel after joining:

      defmodule PhoenixChat.MyChannel do
        use PhoenixChat.Web, :channel
        alias PhoenixChat.Presence

        def join("some:topic", _params, socket) do
          send(self, :after_join)
          {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, ...)}
        end

        def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
          {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user_id, %{
            online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
          })
          push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
          {:noreply, socket}
        end
      end

  In the example above, `Presence.track` is used to register this
  channel's process as a presence for the socket's user ID, with
  a map of metadata. Next, the current presence list for
  the socket's topic is pushed to the client as a `"presence_state"` event.

  Finally, a diff of presence join and leave events will be sent to the
  client as they happen in real-time with the "presence_diff" event.
  See `Phoenix.Presence.list/2` for details on the presence datastructure.

  ## Fetching Presence Information

  The `fetch/2` callback is triggered when using `list/1`
  and serves as a mechanism to fetch presence information a single time,
  before broadcasting the information to all channel subscribers.
  This prevents N query problems and gives you a single place to group
  isolated data fetching to extend presence metadata.

  The function receives a topic and map of presences and must return a
  map of data matching the Presence datastructure:

      %{"123" => %{metas: [%{status: "away", phx_ref: ...}],
        "456" => %{metas: [%{status: "online", phx_ref: ...}]}

  The `:metas` key must be kept, but you can extend the map of information
  to include any additional information. For example:

      def fetch(_topic, entries) do
        query =
          from u in User,
            where: u.id in ^Map.keys(entries),
            select: {u.id, u}

        users = query |> Repo.all |> Enum.into(%{})

        for {key, %{metas: metas}} <- entries, into: %{} do
          {key, %{metas: metas, user: users[key]}}
        end
      end

  The function above fetches all users from the database who
  have registered presences for the given topic. The fetched
  information is then extended with a `:user` key of the user's
  information, while maintaining the required `:metas` field from the
  original presence data.
  """
  use Phoenix.Presence, otp_app: :phoenix_chat,
  pubsub_server: PhoenixChat.PubSub
end
```

I am getting users status using this method `PhoenixChat.RoomChannel`

```
def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
  Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user, %{
    online_at: :os.system_time(:millisecond)
  })
  push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
end
```

In this segment
saving users presence status

```
def connect(%{"user" => user, "status" => status}, socket) do
  Redix.command(:redix, ["SET", user, status]) 
  {:ok, assign(socket, :user, user)}
end
```

I want to get the status not the time.
How can I do this task?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a map with `online_at` as the 3rd argument to `Presence.track/3`. You can just put any other fields in there to track the status. Note that you have to call `Presence.track/3` again when you want to change the status.